# How do I type in multiple languages on elementary OS?

Tags: keyboard, accessibility

I hail from Asia and am fluent in three languages. This means that I often find myself switching keyboards when I have to type. However, I can't seem to find the way to type in other languages beside English (more specifically, Chinese and Japanese). After I install the language pack and select the keyboard layout for these languages as default, all it does when I switch keyboards is allow me to type English with what is basically an English keyboard.

Comment: do you want your keyboard to have a different layout with other characters (but one character per key), or are you looking for more advanced input methods like pinyin?

Answer (score 4):

Go to *Settings - Keyboard - Layout* (3rd tab). Add a new language by clicking the plus sign (+) at the bottom left and selecting it from a list.

[image]

-Tip: You can quickly change between distributions by pressing Alt+Spacebar. The shortkey can be edited under *Settings - Keyboard - Shortcuts - Universal Access - Next Keyboard Layout*

[image]

Also, after adding multiple keyboard layouts, they should be accessible in a panel applet and be switched from there too with the mouse.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in the [russian community](https://elementary.today/forum/671-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B/p4#p8332)

Let me translate it.

1. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
2. `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`
3. Open dconf-editor
4. Go to org > pantheon > desktop > gala > keybindings
5. Set `switch-input-source` and `switch-input-source-backward` to `['']`
6. To enable switching by Alt + Shift execute following command:

`gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Alt>Shift_L', '<Alt>Shift_R']"`

Note: you **must press Alt first** to switch the layout